# NserviceBus omit retry policy

Tags: nservicebus

I have a message handler (implements IHandleMessages) which does some stuff in Handle method.

Is it possible **on certain types of error only**, to omit the retry policy and direct the event to Error queue?

Comment: You only want this behavior on certain exceptions and not others? To be clear, you're talking about overriding the default NServiceBus retry behavior? Have a look at this: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/automatic-retries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by creating a custom retry policy. When an error occurs you can inspect the exception and message info.

```
SecondLevelRetriesSettings retriesSettings = busConfiguration.SecondLevelRetries();
retriesSettings.CustomRetryPolicy(MyCustomRetryPolicy);

TimeSpan MyCustomRetryPolicy(TransportMessage transportMessage)
{
    if (transportMessage.ExceptionType() == typeof(MyBusinessException).FullName)
    {
        // Do not retry for MyBusinessException
        return TimeSpan.MinValue;
    }

    if (transportMessage.NumberOfRetries() >= 3)
    {
        return TimeSpan.MinValue;
    }

    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
}
```

This applies to V5, if you are using a different version check the docs:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/automatic-retries#second-level-retries-custom-retry-policy